# How to authenticate user on android?

Tags: android, asp.net, android-studio

I have a website made on ASP.NET with backend being handled on SQL.I have been working on creating an android app for my website.How do I authenticate/ register a user? Is there any support on android studio for ASP.NET or will I need to use php for authentication?

Comment: Can you return JSON responses from ASP.NET? Oauth2 is the most commonly used authentication

Answer (score 0):

Connected the app directly to MS SQL using jtds and connecting it directly to sql server without using any intermediate scripts